# Creating Chat App with MySql, php ,w/o GCM

Tags: android

I wanna make Chat App using MySql And Php , But in Syria  I can't use GCM 
is there any alternative way to do it? (Not Firebase , or quickblox ) 
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ajax technology, you can build a full web-based chat system, and use Javascript interface to communicate with your app, so that you can notify your app user there is a new message.

BTW, you can modify your question title like **Creating Chat App with MySql, php, w/o GCM**

Comment: aha that cool ... thank you
Can you please Give me a Reference or example for it ?

Comment: Read middle content of URL above, there is a Javascript interface example.

Comment: Thanks ! .. I will take a look at it :)

Comment: sir , it not solve my Problem .. is there any other way ?? 
I've Searched a lot .. but i found nth ..

Comment: Since you mentioned about GCM, I assume that your problem was "no notification way". You can simply create a full web-based chat app, and user ajax to ask your server about new message... Another way you can create a native chat app, and use something like socket, WebService to ask your server about new message.  I think these are enough to solve your question... How about to express how much you understand about "a chat app" ?

Comment: Yes i think The Problem is about my understand about the chat app :( ....

Comment: I assume you understand what is Database, so that you can simply create a table to record every char, from any to anyone, and show it to a receiver...for example, Tom. And what GCM really did is help you to told Tom "Hey Tom, you got new message...". Any more detail like message date(time), is this message been read...I think that's not that hard.

Comment: yes I know that ... but I'm talking about realTime Chat ... 
I'm trying to use the Socket.io with node.js ..

Comment: Even the GCM wasn't real time, and it's even NOT guaranteed that target will received, so DON'T drop into the myth of "real time", just simply make your every delay was acceptable.